# Type conversion in golang

Tags: go, casting

I am a newbie to golang. I have created a couple of custom types and am confused on their behavior differences - I am missing something in my understanding. I searched for a few stack overflow links like [Golang : Type conversion - Converting map[string]string to map[someStruct]string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46861613/golang-type-conversion-converting-mapstringstring-to-mapsomestructstring) but they are not quite addressing this.

My first custom type is a string and other is a map of this custom type to ints.
Sample code below:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type GlobalRuleName string
type RuleConf map[GlobalRuleName]int

func demo(ruleConf RuleConf) {
    fmt.Printf("ruleConf is %+v", ruleConf)
}

func main() {
    var dummyRuleName GlobalRuleName
    dummyRuleName = "dummy"

    dummyRuleConf := make(map[GlobalRuleName]int)
    dummyRuleConf[dummyRuleName] = 23
    demo(dummyRuleConf)

}
```

This runs fine with output
`ruleConf is map[dummy:23]`
 My confusion is why is the variable dummyRuleConf automatically recognized as type ruleConf by Go? I expected demo function to throw an error saying type expected ruleConf.

This does not work with strings the same way. For eg: If I declare a function accepting a GlobalRuleName and pass it a string, it errors out. Sample code below:

```
func demoName(name GlobalRuleName) {
    fmt.Printf("name is %+v", name)

}

and then within main 
foo := "foo"
demoName(foo)
./prog.go:30:10: cannot use foo (type string) as type GlobalRuleName in argument to demoName
```

Complete go playground link here: https://play.golang.org/p/WWO1H5MgLyJ

Why was it able to understand that the dummyRuleConf map declaration matched the custom type for ruleConf but not do so for the string?

Fyi - i created a custom type for strings because it makes my code easier to understand. I read on other SO posts that this is not recommended in Go, will get rid of it.

I need to create the custom type for the map since I want to write methods on that type.

Comment: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignability The second bullet point allows the assignment of values of type RuleConf to variables of type map[GlobalRuleName]int and vice versa. None of the points apply to string and GlobalRuleName.

Comment: Thanks Peter. As per the second bullet: `x's type V and T have identical underlying types and at least one of V or T is not a defined type.`  Not clear on why this is not applicable to string and GlobalRuleName? They share the underlying type. And string is inbuilt, so not a defined type?

Comment: Both `string` and `GlobalRuleName` are defined types. See https://golang.org/ref/spec#String_types which says "The predeclared string type is string; **it is a defined type**." (Emphasis mine.)

Comment: Thanks Torek, that clears it up for me. I got confused because https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_definitions mentioned `The new type is called a defined type`, so I thought only new user specified types fall in that category.

Answer (score 0):

You first piece of code works because you have already declared your variable `dummyRuleName` to be of type `GlobalRuleName` before the assignment. That way the compiler knows `dummyRuleName` can be used as the key in `RuleConf`.

Go is strongly typed language. There is no automatic type casting between different types of variable. You need to explicitly type the variables to make them assignable to each other, even if the underlying type is the same. For example,

```golang
var foo GlobalRuleName
foo = "foo" // because "foo" string literal is not a defined type
demoName(foo)
```

or

```golang
foo := GlobalRuleName("foo")
demoName(foo)
```

You can also cast the variable [when used](https://play.golang.org/p/54_GZ2PvOq1):

```golang
foo := "foo"
demoName(GlobalRuleName(foo))
```